# How to change the color of Google Maps on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, colors

I am currently developing an android application that uses the latest version of Google Maps API... My application is an exploration application wherein by default, the unexplored part of the map should be colored (overlayed?) as gray or black....  As of now, I already got the solution for getting the location via GPS then storing it in an internal database.

My Question is that **how can I set the color of my MAP into Gray or Black by default?**. i have here an image of a similar Application called UMBRA... too bad I can't post pics yet, so ill just give the link instead.

[Umbra Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.unchiujar.umbra)

Comment: I want to cover the map with GRAY or BLACK color (Fog Effect).... then once the user explores that specific area, the color of that area will turn back into normal.

Comment: Hello, did you figure out an answer for it? I am running into the same thing